# Tutorials for creating an ActiveX Control in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, activexobject

I need to write an ActiveX control and have never written one before.

I'd appreciate being pointed to some useful tutorials.

I'm also wanting to implement it under Code::Blocks.  Has anyone done this before? how easy is it?

Note: I've found a number of tutorials, but they are either for visual basic, or visual c++ based.  these tools do all the hard work for you.  I need to implement it from scratch with Code::Blocks as I do not have those other tools available.

Comment: This is what I'm after
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751629/developing-activex-controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) has an ActiveX control made without the use of Visual C++ libraries. You can have a look at the git repository [here](http://tinyurl.com/yg9aamg)

Answer (score 0):

As I thought, it looks like I need to write the COM interfaces myself.  I'll need to
start with a DLL project in Code::Blocks

Found these two tutorials which look like they are heading down the right track.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/comintro.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/comintro2.aspx