# How to create a ControlSource ms-access property in c++ without VB6

Tags: c++, ms-access, mfc, vb6-migration, activexobject

I'm trying to create a MFC ActiveX control with Visual Studio 2022, that should have a  `ControlSource` property under Data Category when inserted in ms-access form. So that it would be possible to bind that property within ms-access.

I found following VB6-code on internet but i have no clue how to implement this with modern c++. `MemberInfo`, `VB_ProcData` and `VB_MemberFlags` and `VB_UserMemId` seem to be the important part for what i need.

Does anyone know if it's currently possible to create such property, and how that would be done?

in c++ or .net visual basic or c#? Or knows any documentation links for `VB_ProcData` and such?

```
'WARNING! DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE FOLLOWING COMMENTED LINES!
'MemberInfo=13,0,0,
Public Property Get DataString() As String
Attribute DataString.VB_Description = "Data to be encoded to QR Code"
Attribute DataString.VB_ProcData.VB_Invoke_Property = ";Data"
Attribute DataString.VB_UserMemId = 0
Attribute DataString.VB_MemberFlags = "224"
    DataString = m_DataString
End Property

Public Property Let DataString(ByVal New_DataString As String)
    m_DataString = New_DataString
End Property
```

source: [Making QRCode ActiveX Control for MS Access: Control Source Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53244605/making-qrcode-activex-control-for-ms-access-control-source-property)

The following setup seems to work: win10-64+office2007+visual studio 6.

For now I'm going to embed my vs2019-c++ ActiveX control in a UserControl in visual studio 6-ocx, and create events/properties where needed. Of course I would prefer 1 ocx, but integration in access is much more important.

Still I'm looking for a way to do that with vs2019, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your link iOS to creating a control with VB6, not what you want.  I believe what you want is creating an activex/ocx control with c++.  Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751629/developing-activex-controls

Comment: I know i can create an ActiveX control in c++, but I want it to have properties like ControlSource and RowSource as in msaccess,, which can be created with vb in vs6,.But till now no luck, can't find no documentation, and crashes with the things i tried in c++.

Comment: Have you looked at the type library of one of the Office controls?

Comment: Perhaps these statements generate [custom MIDL attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/custom)?